# Node.js's python child script outputting on finish, not real time

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, buffer, stdout

I am new to node.js and socket.io and I am trying to write a small server that will update a webpage based on python output.

Eventually this will be used for a temperature sensor so for now I have a dummy script which prints temperature values every few seconds:

**Thermostat.py**

```
import random, time
for x in range(10):
    print(str(random.randint(23,28))+" C")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.4,5))
```

Here's a cut down version of the server:

**Index.js**

```
var sys   = require('sys'), 
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn, 
    thermostat = spawn('python', ["thermostat.py"]),
    app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http);

thermostat.stdout.on('data', function (output) { 
    var temp = String(output);
    console.log(temp);
    io.sockets.emit('temp-update', { data: temp});
}); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
```

And finally the web page:

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Live temperature</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="liveTemp">Loading...</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('temp-update', function (msg) {
        $('#liveTemp').html(msg.data)
    });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is nodejs seems to recieve all of the temperature values at once, and instead of getting 10 temperature values at random intervals, I get *all* of the values in one long string after the script has finished:

[image: lots of temp values]
[image: console output]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to disable output buffering in python. This can be done many different ways, including:

- Setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable
- Passing the `-u` switch to the python executable
- Calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after each write (or `print()` in your case) to stdout
- For Python 3.3+ you can pass `flush=true` to `print()`: `print('Hello World!', flush=True)`

Additionally, in your node code, (even though you have a sleep in your python code and you are now flushing stdout) you really should not assume that `output` in your 'data' handler for `thermostat.stdout` is always going to be just one line.

Comment: sys.stdout.flush() did it!

Comment: This is a great solution but not really an answer.  Why do I need to disable output buffering? Shouldn't node recieve buffered stdout just as the command line recieves it?  

Disabling buffering means that if you need to throttle the output then you basically have to rewrite buffering logic yourself, which seems silly when python has the feature builtin.

Comment: @Almenon There is no issue on node's side here. The node process cannot receive something that hasn't been written yet by the python process.

Comment: then why can the command line receive output in real-time without the -u switch being specified?

Comment: @Almenon because when you're running the Python script directly from your terminal, stdout is pointing to a tty and not a pipe. When stdout is a pipe, output is fully buffered. When stdout is a tty, output is line buffered. You can verify this by spawning the python process with `stdio: [0, 1, 2]` set in your node `spawn()` options. This tells node to pass the parent process's stdin, stdout, and stderr fds to the spawned process instead of setting up pipes. With this setting, you will see each printed line as soon as it's printed by the python process.