# Error running socket.io and express-nodejs setup

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, socket.io

I was working on nodejs executing python scripts using spawn and socket.io methods. I am getting output on the console. but I am not able to display it on the browser. It is showing error.I have pasted the error below. Can any one please help me in solving this problem. I have got this example from [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607799/node-jss-python-child-script-outputting-on-finish-not-real-time)
Here i am pasting my code: **sample.py**

```
import random, time
for x in range(10):
print(str(random.randint(23,28))+" C")
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.4,5))
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http); 

var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.post('/showtemp',function(req,res){
   var pathtoScript = spawn('python', ["../External_scripts/sample.py"]);
    pathtoScript.stdout.on('data', function (output) { 
    var val = String(output);
    console.log(val);
    io.sockets.emit('response', { data: val});
});
})
var server = app.listen(8082,'0.0.0.0', function () {

  var port = server.address().port

console.log("App is listening at %s", port)

});
```

And **index.html** page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live temperature</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="liveTemp">Loading...</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('response',function(msg){
            console.log("msg");
            $('#liveTemp').html(msg.data);
        })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error

```
GET http://localhost:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQSVrTN 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8082/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQSVrTN 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't started a web server anywhere or hooked socket.io to it.  There are several different ways to do this, but here's one that works:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);
```

Note: You must see a `server.listen()` (or equivalent) somewhere.  **And, you need to pass the server to socket.io so it can hook into it.**

You can also do this where you don't directly need to load the `http` module yourself:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

socket.io documentation for several different options [here](http://socket.io/docs/).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post this. Here I am starting the server. `var server = app.listen(8082,'0.0.0.0', function () {

  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("App is listening at %s", port)

});`

Comment: @naik3 - I can't respond to code you don't show.  Can't help unless you post the real code.  The error you see looks like you aren't hooking socket.io up to your server properly.  This line `var io = require('socket.io')(http);` is not correct.

Comment: @naik3 - Use the "edit" link to correct your question so I can see things in context.  Regardless of the above code, you still aren't initializing socket.io properly.  Questions should stand on their own without people having to read comments elsewhere in order to understand the question.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Here I have edited the code. can you please help. I have changed this line **var http = require('http').Server(app);**, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Getting output on console.. Not able to display it on yo browser... ?? Is there any routing error...??

Comment: I don't see any `var socket = io()` in index.html.

Comment: @naik3 - And, now your index.js code shows no definition of the `app` variable.  I'm about to stop helping you because of regularly incomplete code that makes it impossible to know what you're actually missing and thus frustrating to try to help you.  This is just really an unorganized question.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 - I have edited the code please help me to find the solution. Still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @naik3 - Just pick one of the sequences of code I offered you and use that - they work - I've given you two possible answers to choose from.  Yours is creating two separate servers and the one that socket.io is bound to is not started.  `app.listen()` creates a new server and that one is NOT connected to socket.io.  The server that is connected to socket.io is not started.

Comment: @naik3 - FYI, you can see the code for `app.listen()` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615) and see that it creates a new server that is different from the one you connected socket.io to.  So the server you connected socket.io to is NEVER started and thus socket.io doesn't work.  You need to connect socket.io to the server that is started.

Comment: Ok, I will check it.. Thank you for the explanation. It helped me to understand the concept.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, Sorry sir, I tried what u said, I am really bad at this, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kk8WgQ5LKxllkjChRAnS?p=info) I am pasting my code in plunker. please help me.

Comment: @naik3 - The code in that plunker does not fix the things I asked you to fix.  You're still hooking socket.io to the wrong server.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I have fixed what ever you have told. Now i am getting the error once I click submit button. Same error.

Comment: @naik3 - Getting what error?  FYI, your socket connection code in app.js needs to be done long before you do the `$http.post()`.  You need to socket.io connection up and running before the post happens and you need it to only be established once.  Does the error happen from `var socket = io()`?  Is that the line of code in the client that causes the error?  To help you further, I will need to see the "current" version of your code with your fixes.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, For better understand on the concept of socket.io, i have started with a simple program. Which is pretty similar to what I am looking for, I have posted a [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064337/error-running-socket-io-and-express-nodejs) question. Please help me solving the problem.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, can you please help me in solving [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264281/socket-io-is-not-emitting-value) problem.