# Not able to print value emitted by socket.io and express-nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I am facing a problem in socket.io. My code is not emitting **value** on particular route. On '/' this route it is working fine, but once I click submit button, route changes to '/process_post' there I am not able to catch the emitted values by sock.io. please help me to solve the problem. Here I am pasting my code. 
server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('public'));

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})

app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
       first_name:req.body.first_name,
       last_name:req.body.last_name
   };
   console.log(response);
    io.of('/process_post').on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    console.log('a user connected');
  });

res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/process_post" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br>

Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at their docs: http://socket.io/docs/#restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace

When instantiating your socket on the front end it needs to connect to the namespace you set.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/process_post');
```

Also I would remove the socket declaration outside your route on the backend, otherwise the event handlers would not be attached due to that part of code not being called until the route is hit which would be after the initial socket connection.

Comment: Hi .. Thank you for the reply. But still its not working.